# first character of a string using strncpy bug

Tags: c

I wanted to get the first character of a string using `strncpy`, here's my code

```
int main() {

    char s[] = "abcdefghi";
    char c[] = "";
    printf("%c\n",c);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    strncpy(c,s,1); 
    printf("%c\n",c);
    printf("%s\n",s);   
    return 0;   
}
```

The problem is that `c` is still an empty string, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your format doesn't match the type you pass. You should pass `*c` or `c[0]`. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Moreover, strncpy() is not the best way to make the copy as it works on strings. In C, a string is a suite of chars terminated by the NULL character (`\0'). But c is a table of one char. You must have at least 2 slots to store the NULL char at the end. Use something like "c[0] = s[1]" instead.

Comment: Activate compiler warnings

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `c` is an array (which decays into a pointer), while the `%c` format of `printf()` requires a character. If you pass the pointer when the function expects a character, you get undefined behavior, and a possible output will be the first byte of the address of the array, interpreted as an ASCII character.

Also, please note that `char c[] = "";` simply declares an array of length 1 which contains the null (`\0`) character. If you try to print that, like you do in your code, you will likely get weird output.

If `c` is meant to only store a single character, declare it as a simple `char` variable, and pass it's address to `strncpy()`:

```
char s[] = "abcdefghi";
char c = ' ';
printf("%c\n", c);
printf("%s\n", s);
strncpy(&c, s, 1); //notice the & before c
printf("%c\n", c);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

However, you have to be careful. Passing any value greater than 1 to `strncpy()` asks for big trouble, since you would be writing to an undefined location.

Answer (score -1):

s is an array of 10 chars, c is an array with one char. Do you understand why? And which char is stored in c?

%s is the format for strings, %c is the format for chars. But c is not a char. An array containing one char is an array, not a char. So when you try to print c you get rubbish.

Now the bad one: strncpy in your case doesn’t produce a C string because there isn’t enough space for one. If you try to print c with %c you get nonsense. If you try to print it with %s you get undefined behaviour. Do NOT use strncpy unless you really know what it is doing (you should generally avoid strncpy).